# How to add xib cell's button action in HomeVC in swift

Tags: swift, button, uicollectionview, cell

I have created xib collectionview cell.. and i am able to use all its values in HomeVC like below

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {

super.viewDidLoad()
let nib = UINib(nibName: "MainCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
collectionView.registerNib(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MainCollectionViewCell")

 }

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MainCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainCollectionViewCell

 cell.arrivingLabel.text = indexData.arriv
 cell.lblDiscountedPrice.text = indexData.discPrice

 
return cell
}
```

like below i can give action to xib cell button, **but i want xib cell button action in `HomeVC` class** how, please guide me here

```
   cell.btnDetails.addTarget(self, action: #selector(connected(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

   @objc func connected(sender: UIButton){
  }
```

**i want xib cell's button action in HomeVC**

```
 @IBAction func productDetailsMain(_ sender: UIButton){
  }
```

**note**: if i use same collectionview cell then i can drag from HomeVC button action outlet to collectionview cell button then its adding.. but if i use xib cell in collectionview then this process is not working.. how to give xib cell button action in HomeVC class

Screenshot: not able to connect action outlet in HomeVC

[image]

Comment: Show a screenshot or two.  I don't see the relationship between your xib file and the button in HomeVC.

Comment: @ElTomato added SS of HomeVC `productDetailsMain` method not connecting

Comment: Use the closure.

Comment: or use the custom delegate method.

Comment: look like "delegate" is what you need

Answer (score 0):

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {

super.viewDidLoad()
let nib = UINib(nibName: "MainCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
collectionView.registerNib(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MainCollectionViewCell")

 }

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MainCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainCollectionViewCell
 cell.btnDetails.tag = indexPath.row// it will identify the tapped button cell index
cell.btnDetails.addTarget(self, action: #selector(connected(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
 cell.arrivingLabel.text = indexData.arriv
 cell.lblDiscountedPrice.text = indexData.discPrice

 
return cell
}

@objc func connected(sender: UIButton){
    let tag = sender.tag
    print(tag)

  }
```

Comment: i want cell's button action in HomeVC

Comment: like this `@IBAction func productDetailsMain(_ sender: UIButton){
  }
 `

Comment: just simply add button action on the controller and connect it to your cell button. But my above solution is more helpful for future use.

Comment: my problem is.. with xib cell button i am not able to do like `add button action on the controller and connect it to your cell button`

Comment: for xib you can't do an action like that you need to create an action target of the cell button.